# Does fplutil support arm64? Any native profiler tool support arm64?

Tags: android, native, profiler

Can I use fplutil to profile app run on arm64? Or is there any small change I can make to the source to make it support arm64? I have tryed android-ndk-profiler and found that it doesn't work on arm64. It seems that ndk doesn't surport -pg at all so it is hard to modify. So any native profiler tool like fplutil and android-ndk-profiler recommanded that support arm64?